# Trying to scan and print a string in a structure

Tags: c, string, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct veiculos
{
    char modelo[20];
    char marca[20];
    int ano;
    int preco;
}Vei;

int main()
{
    Vei v1, v2;

    scanf("%s", &v1.modelo);
    scanf("%s", &v1.marca);
    scanf("%d", &v1.ano);
    scanf("%d", &v1.preco);

    scanf("%s", &v2.modelo);
    scanf("%s", &v2.marca);
    scanf("%d", &v2.ano);
    scanf("%d", &v2.preco);

    if(v1.ano == v2.ano)
    {
        if(v1.preco < v2.preco)
        {
            printf("%s %s", v1.marca, v1.modelo);
        }
        else printf("%s %s", v2.marca, v2.modelo);
    }
    if(v1.ano < v2.ano)
    {
        printf("%s %s", v1.marca, v1.modelo);
    }
    else printf("%s %s", v2.marca, v2.modelo);
}
```

Im always getting this ERROR, have tried multiple things.

```
In function 'int main()':
warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[20]' [-Wformat=]
   19 |     scanf("%s", &v1.modelo);
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try: `&v1.modelo` -> `v1.modelo`

Comment: oh, that worked thx for the help. but why i dont need the & in this case?

Comment: In this case, array name is a pointer to its first element. So `v1.modelo` is equivalent to `&v1.modelo[0]`

Comment: Tip: When you get an error you don't understand just paste the entire msg into your favourite search engine and see what it comes up with. Can get a faster answer than posting on Stack Overflow.